# Supersymmetry as a solution of hierarchy problem

Tags: supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, fine-tuning

[Hierarchy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_problem) is the statement of why the weak force is much stronger than gravity. 
In terms of coupling constant, weak force (Fermi coupling) is much larger than gravity (Newton's constant).

I want to know how supersymmetry can be a solution to Hierarchy problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all about appropriate cancellations in the expansions when calculating the Feynman diagrams:

> [The hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry#The_hierarchy_problem) problem
>
> Supersymmetry close to the electroweak scale ameliorates the hierarchy problem that afflicts the Standard Model. In the Standard Model, the electroweak scale receives enormous Planck-scale quantum corrections. The observed hierarchy between the electroweak scale and the Planck scale must be achieved with extraordinary fine tuning. In a supersymmetric theory, on the other hand, Planck-scale quantum corrections cancel between partners and superpartners (owing to a minus sign associated with fermionic loops). The hierarchy between the electroweak scale and the Planck scale is achieved in a natural manner, without miraculous fine-tuning.

Comment: SUSY by the introduction of partner particles explains why the natural Higgs can be at EWK scale. But the weak gravity as compared to other forces is still not explained. :/

Comment: @23rduser The trivial solution is that gravity is not a force. It certainly doesn't behave like one. The real problem with the problem is the assumption that it is despite all the evidence that it isn't.